# Function runs in VBA but not the spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have what I think is a relatively simple function I'm running where I'm basically trying to find how much time someone stays waiting in the queue for a call back. It runs great when I'm in the VBA tab, but when I call the function in my spreadsheet I get a #REF! error.

```
    Function TIQ2()

    Dim time, count, i As Integer
    Dim TIQ
    time = 0
    count = 0

    NumRows = Sheet1.Range("A2", Sheet1.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.count + 1

    For i = 2 To NumRows
        If Sheet1.Range("c" & i) = "no" Or Sheet1.Range("c" & i) = "No" Then
    
            If Sheet1.Range("d" & i) = "No" Or Sheet1.Range("d" & i) = "no" Then
            time = time + Left(Sheet1.Range("g" & i), 2)
            count = count + 1
            Debug.Print time, count
        End If
    End If
  Next

  TIQ2 = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(time / count, 0) & " minutes"
  Debug.Print TIQ2

End Function
```

Comment: How are you calling the function in the spreadsheet?

Comment: Problematic: you're [finding the last row the wrong way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba), you have undeclared variables (`NumRows`), `Dim time, count, i As Integer` only declares `i` as `Integer`, the rest are `Variant`, but you should probably use `Long` instead of `Integer`.

Comment: ...and specify `Option Explicit` at the top of the module

Comment: There's also an implicit conversion in `time + Left(Sheet1.Range("g" & i), 2)` that should probably be explicit using `CLng`. Lots of implicit `.Value`s too: `Sheet1.Range("c" & i).Value`.

Comment: See all remarks above: first a tip, try not use VBA names as variables (time and count) but regarding your question: Your Function name is also a cell address: TIQ2 Change this name!

Answer (score 0):

try changing this line. some excel function requieres this syntaxis

```
 TIQ2 = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(time / count, 0) & " minutes"

'-------------------
 TIQ2 =ThisWorkbook.Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(time / count, 0) & " minutes"
```

Comment: @BigBen I feel ya brother.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

'Public Function fnHelloWorld()
'Function fnTIQ()
Function TIQ2()
    MsgBox "Hello World!"
End Function

Sub Test()
    Call TIQ2
End Sub
```

Try this ...

The first two function declarations work OK but the third one does not. The #REF error is produced by the fact that the TIQ2 function name is also a cell reference as @EvR says.